# How to update API path dynamically in VUEX state

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am trying to dynamically update the API path in my Vuex state. Vuex must have a default path "example.com/api/datasetA.json" set when the page loaded and I want to update the path to "example.com/api/datasetB.json" by the user interaction and fetch the new API data immediately.

The relevant part of my code is as follows (updated code):

VUEX:

```
export const state = () => ({
  apiData: [],
  apiId: 'datasetA.json'
});

export const mutations = {
  fillApiData: (state, data) => {state.apiData = data},
  updateApi: (state, newApiId) => {state.apiId = newApiId;}
};

export const actions = {
  async getApiData({commit, state}) {
    const response = await this.$axios.$get('https://example/api/'+state.apiId);
    commit('fillApiData', response);
```

then VUE method as follows:

```
methods: {

   updateApi(apiId) {
    
      this.$store.commit('updateApi', apiId)
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mutation that changes the vuex state. Then run this mutation(commit) in the `getApiData` function

```js
export const state = () => ({
  apiData: [],
  apiId: 'datasetA.json'
});

export const mutations = {
  updateAPI(state, newApiId ) {
    state.apiId = newApiId;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  async getApiData({commit, state}) {
    const response = await this.$axios.$get('https://example/api/'+state.apiId);
    commit('updateValue', response);
    commit('updateAPI', 'some.new.datasetB.json');
  }
}
```

> I can update the state directly by using this.$store.state.apiId = apiId in methods but I know this is bad practice

You are correct. However, if you would like that approach to update the state outside Vuex, you can use mutations to change the Vuex - This is good practice.

Then you can do

```js
this.$store.commit('updateAPI', 'my new value')
```

Comment: I tried the longer approach and I get the following error: [vuex] unknown action type: updateAPI after triggering the user action:  `methods: {  updateAPI(apiId) {
    
      this.$store.dispatch('updateAPI', apiId)
      },`

Comment: **dispatch** - is used for actions.  **commit** - is used for mutations. So you have to change `this.$store.dispatch('updateAPI', apiId)` to `this.$store.commit('updateAPI', apiId)`

Comment: changing it to commit did the trick. However, I noticed that the API data does not update on its own. Is there a straightforward way to trigger a call to fetch the new API data from the updated url simultaneously with the commit?

Comment: Yes, then you would have to do the first approach I posted above; You fetch the API data via the **action** `getApiData`, and inside that function, you do a **mutation** (commit) to update the state.

Comment: I updated my original code with your example to my initial question. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly now because while the API url is updated, the user interaction still does not trigger a fetch for datasetB.  In your code you have `commit('updateAPI', 'some.new.datasetB.json');` but this will change the API url without user interaction.